# tracking editing values from Google Form

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I've a google form, and I split data based on sections. I've 3 sections for example and data is get separated into 3 different sheets when user submits the form, I've successfully done it using form events, but now I want to know how I can track changes if user edits the form and make those fields red.
Sorry I am not including the code, here just want to know about suggestion to do it?

Can you suggest methods I can use for this?

Comment: you write ` edit the form` , would you mean rather `edit the responses stored in the sheets`  ?

Comment: @MikeSteelson No, editing the form response directly, using edit your response button. than because I split the data into 3 sheets based on 3 section in form, if someone change something while editing I actually need to track the change and highlight the cell which has new value

Comment: ok, thx, so I will let somebody else answer (event if I will test on my side something). in fact, after a test, I even don't know how to edit the response!

Answer (score 1):

#### Get response id:

Assuming you are using an [onFormSubmit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/form-trigger-builder#onFormSubmit()) trigger (for Forms, not for Sheets), you can use the corresponding [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit_1) to get information about the form response.

More specifically, you can retrieve the form response `id`, which will be the same every time the form response is edited, as well as the different form item ids. You can use these field to identify the response in your sheet and each of the corresponding items and update those. For example, if this was your trigger function:

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  const responseId = e.response.getId();
  const itemResponses = e.response.getItemResponses();
  itemResponses.forEach(itemResponse => {
    const response = itemResponse.getResponse();
    const itemId = itemResponse.getItem().getId();
    // Find cells with corresponding responseId and itemId
    // Update cells if found, populate new ones if it's a new submission
  });  
}
```

#### Find cells in spreadsheet:

Then you should find the `responseId` in your spreadsheet. You can use [Range.getValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) to look for the sheet values or, if you feel so inclined, use [TextFinder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder) to find the corresponding cell.

#### Update cells:

Once you've identified the cells, you can update the corresponding values ([Range.setValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)) and/or update the background color ([Range.setBackgrounds](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setbackgroundscolor)).

#### Note:

- This solution requires you to add the different `responseId` and `itemId` for every form response in your sheets. Otherwise, there will be no way to identify these whenever a response is submitted or edited.
- The exact workflow for this would depend on the data structure you have, the form items you want to track, etc.